# Angular with Bootstrap Modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal page that works if I request it with its own URL but If request it as modal, modal page popup works but angular is not working. I see {{post.name}} in name input.

I am calling my modal page with:

```
<a class="btn btn-ext-darkblue btn-modal-trigger btn-ext-darkblue savestockbtn" href="/admin.brands/edit?brandid={{post.brandid}}" data-toggle="modal"><tags:label text="edit"/></a>
```

Here is my modal page:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="tags"%>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" class="span6" data-popup="modal">
    <div class="row-fluid sortable">
<div class="box span12" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="box-content">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action='/admin.brands/update' data-toggle="validate" method="post" ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
                <input type="hidden" name="brandid" value="{{post.brandid}}"/>
                <div class="section-heading"></div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="selectError"><tags:label text="name"/> *</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input name="name" value="{{post.name}}" required/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="selectError"><tags:label text="isactive"/> </label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="post.isactive" name="isactive" value="1"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <a href="/admin.brands" class="btn btn-ext-lightblue"><tags:label text="close"/></a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-ext-darkblue btn-disable-on-submit" ><tags:label text="save"/></button>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<script>

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var brandId = getParameterByName('brandid');

var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("PostsCtrl",  function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('http://localhost/admin.brands/getJsonBrandAndEdit?brandid=' + brandId).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.post = data;

        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I make it work ? What is the problem ?

Comment: Have you seen BootstrapUI, they are directives created by the angular team for bootstrap? [link](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: You are no where calling the the modal to open in JS.. If you aren't using angular-ui (Angular JS + BootStrap), what method are you using to invoke the modal and are you invoking from HTML or JS?

Comment: I saw but I am very new at angular, do you have a detailled documents ?

Isn't there any way to do it without BootstrapUI ?

Comment: BootstrapUI is the most apt way of doing it in Angular JS. Everything will else will ask you to use jQuery with in the controller if you are invoking from JS